# Add a way to see a list of all "dead" inter-network links

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, moderator-tools, 10k-tools

I've recently encountered a question which had a link to a different question which was deleted - in essence, a dead link to anyone except 10k-ers. Is there some way to see a list of posts containing such dead links across an entire site - perhaps as a 10k tool or mod tool - in order to occasionally edit the links out of the posts? And if there is no such a thing, can one be added?

This could also be expanded to include links across sites but which are still inside the SE network.

If this is implemented, though, meta sites should be exempt from this.

Comment: On MSO, half the links are to 10k posts :/

Comment: Why would we want to edit these links out? They're dead to some, but not all.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta to the vast majority of users browsing a site, they represent dead links. Dead links are a Bad Thing. Why not remove them?

Comment: Because they're not dead links. They're links that are inaccessible to some, but contain valuable archival data to others. Maybe you're looking for a callout on the links, indicating if they're accessible to you or not?

Comment: I see your edit ("*If this is implemented, though, meta sites should be exempt from this.*"). That could make this make sense.